# WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class

Tags: ios, watchkit

```
the app was working fine, I was doing some adjustment and suddenly it stopped loading. 
I launch the simulator and the storyboard doesn't start.
I get this error:

WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class 
2016-01-18 11:56:30.019 ABWatch Extension[13593:122454] WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class '_TtC17ABWatch_Extension23HomeInterfaceController' to instantiate
2016-01-18 11:56:30.027 ABWatch Extension[13593:122426] *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:35160002 not found
```

Comment: have you made changes on storyboard with any interface controller's property named `Idetifier`?

Answer (score 3):

Please check Initial View Controller in WatchKit App.
Make sure you are using proper identifier for Interface View Controller.

[image]

Also make sure that you are not combining hierarchical and page-based interface styles.

I also face same issue with same error.

I just replace pushController with presentController.
If you are using 
`self.pushControllerWithName("EnterPin", context: nil)` then replace with

```
self.presentControllerWithName("EnterPin", context: nil)
```

I am using code to present View contoller.

```
    @IBAction func pushToEnterPinController() {

         self.presentControllerWithName("EnterPin", context: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me updating the Module under Custom class from the above screenshot worked.(i changed my app name)

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder set the right Module on your InterfaceController's Custom Class section. It is probably empty. [Image illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O88IV.png)